# Prove that this is a smooth surface

Tags: differential-geometry

S is the surface satisfying
$$f(x, y, z) = z^2 + (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-a)^2 -r^2 =0$$
where $a,r\in\mathbb{R}$
Prove that $S$ is a smooth surface.

Do we differentiate with respect to $x, y$ and $z$ separately to show they're all continuous, or is there something more? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Check that $0$ is a regular value of $f$. That is, check that $Df(x,y,z)$ is surjective for all $(x,y,z) \in f^{-1}(0)$. Since the codomain has dimension $1$, this is equivalent to $\nabla f (x,y,z) \neq {\bf 0}$ for all $(x,y,z)\in f^{-1}(0)$. In this condition, $f^{-1}(0)$ is a smooth surface.

Comment: Okay so I've found 4 points where f(p)=0, which are (a, 0, r), (-a, 0, r), (0, a, r), (0, -a, r). Do I just sub these in to the derivatives to make sure they don't equal 0? Also, is every point either a critical value or a regular value, or are there some which re neither?

Comment: Maybe you meant 4 points where Df(p) = 0? If Df(p) is not surjective then p is a critical point, and it is not a critical point otherwise. Being a regular value is a property discussed for elements in the codomain of the function.